# Javascript prompt box without the cancel button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

Is there a way to create a input prompt box that doesn't have the cancel button,
or doesn't allow the user to close the prompt until some value is entered?

Comment: Why don't you just imitate the prompt then you can style how you want?

Comment: Prompt boxes are simplistic. They don't have any logic. You can either create your own Modal Dialog with some logic, or apply the logic to the Prompt Box Response after the response is received and re-show the box if the response doesn't meet your criteria. Since this happens pretty fast, your user will be unlikely to know it went away and restarted. This also allows you the opportunity to alter the text in the prompt to show your dismay at the improper response. But as pointed out by others: You should probably just build a modal dialog to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put your `promt` inside a while loop and continue asking for input until user gives any.

```
do{
    input = prompt("Give input");
}while(input == null || input == "" );

console.log(input);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/d0kgt77o/)

[***Note :*** It's a way to fulfill your requirement that I won't suggest as it may annoy user. You can go with regular expression if you want user to complete your form.]

Comment: Maybe because the OP Asked to remove the cancel button

Comment: OP also mentioned `doesn't allow the user to close the prompt until some value is entered`.

Comment: @Ashad Shanto, thanks, its impossible to remove the cancel button, but this does the trick.

Comment: This is just a horrible, horrible user experience, and (as Hudixt pointed out) doesn't do what the question requested: Hide the Cancel button.

Comment: I already mentioned that as a note. But also said `doesn't allow the user to close the prompt until some value is entered`. What about that. I just gave him a way.

Comment: Luckily Chrome will ask the user if the page should be allowed to pop up any more crap. Some ransomware have managed to hack that too.

Answer (score 4):

Not using `prompt`, no. You have to use modern techniques, presenting a `div` or similar on top of the page and disabling clicks elsewhere, and allowing for the asynchronous nature of that in the code calling it. You can roll your own, or use any of the **many** libraries that do it for you. Search for "JavaScript modal dialog" to find a huge range of choices.

Here's an example using Bootstrap, but that's just one of *many* options available:

```js
$("#the-modal")
  .on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    // When the modal is about to be shown, clear the field
    $(this).find(".field").val("");
    $(this).find(".btn-primary").prop("disabled", true);
  })
  .on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    // When the modal has been shown, focus the field
    $(this).find(".field").focus();
  })
  .on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
    // When the modal is closed, display the field's value
    display("Done, entered value: " + $(this).find("input").val());
  })
  .find(".field").on("keypress input paste change", function() {
    // When the field's value changes in any way, enable/disable
    // the 'Save Changes' button
    $("#the-modal .btn-primary").prop(
      "disabled",
      $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
    );
  });

function display(msg) {
  $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click me" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#the-modal">
  <div id="the-modal" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Please provide the info:
          <input type="text" class="form-control field">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" disabled>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt you can edit the browsers in-built alert, prompt or confirm alerts. However, you could create your own popup which the user couldn't close unless they entered something... but even this way, the user could still edit the HTML of the page or disable javascript. If it's imperative that the user enters something into the box without being able to close it you should include some sort of server-side check. Anything within the clients browser is never really unclosable.